# Element gets blue background in Safari, Chrome and FF is ok

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a button that opens and closes a side navigation which is CSS animated through transitions. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox and kind of works on Safari too but the the button gets this blue background that has not been included anywhere on the CSS rules so it looks like this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

I've been trying to find a solution and included the *backface-visibility: hidden* and *transform: translateZ(0)* and even change colors to RGBA but those hacks didn't do anything.

The bug can be seen is this half [developed website](http://www.zoada.com/barents/report2015/low.html).

Comment: I can't reproduce on Chrome.

Comment: @Andrew, You mean can't reproduce de error?  It's because it works as expected in Chrome and FF.  The problem shows up in Safari.

Comment: Oh sorry, I read the question title wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I noticed that if I changed CSS rules such as *height*, *width* or *translate* using Safari's Web Inspector on the *#nav-toggler* or *#nav-toggler.open* element the circle was repainted to its assigned colour.

So I added `transform: translateZ(1px);` to *#nav-toggler.open* to force a repaint and it solved the problem.

```
#nav-toggler.open {
left: 240px;
transform: translateZ(1); /* added to solve repaint in Safari */
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

I initially added `width:50.00001px` instead but even though it is only 0.00001 of a pixel it was really disturbing to me.